# Discord bot wont read emote from user

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

```js
if (command === 'start') {
 // code to excute when discord user types !start
 message.channel.send(' like counting started!');
} else if (message.content === ':likeyes:') {
 // checks discord user emote
 message.channel.send('thanks for like!');
} //outputs text
```

I'm trying to have a `Discord.js` bot count an emote (`:likeyes:`) in a channel called likes. so basicaly how this works is when the user says `:likeyes:`, the bot will count that and display the number of times the emote has been used.

For example:

```
User: ":likeyes:"
Bot: "The current count is for :likeyes: is 10"
```

The problem is that the bot can't read emotes in my discord server. I havent coded the counting function yet as I am still figuring out how to make the bot read the emote.

Answer (score 1):

You have to send the emoji like this:
`<:EmojiName:EmojiID>` - for animated emojis: `<a:EmojiName:EmojiID>`.
You can get this format by sending `\:emoji:` in a text channel.

Comment: basically already done that this what happens https://prnt.sc/uml2z4

Comment: It seems like that you're not storing the status of counting being enabled. Right now you're checking if the content is "!start" and then if it is the emoji. This will never work, as you can't chain such things into one function

Comment: so basically  by the code I did it, its impossiable to read an emote? btw as I have no idea on how to use advanced javascirpt code  still a noobie